# What does a protoype do in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, oop, object, inheritance, prototype

I've gone through loads and loads of docs online, but I find I need more from Prototypes than I'm currently getting.

Can anyone give me a basic introduction of how prototypes work? When I say "basic introduction", I'm referring to a simple explanation that a junior programmer can understand!

Comment: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/ff852808.aspx

Comment: I learned from this, very good documentation: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/prototype

Comment: http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_object_prototypes.asp

Comment: Verbatim close reason: Questions asking us to recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam. Instead, describe the problem and what has been done so far to solve it.

Comment: Suggest it's important to help this particular user learn and this takes priority. IMO.

Comment: @PeterDavidCarter that's not at all how SO is run. we operate more on "broken windows theory." and a record of downvoted / closed questions for a new user often leads to a total question ban, just saying.

Comment: There you go: https://github.com/getify/You-Dont-Know-JS/blob/master/this%20&%20object%20prototypes/ch5.md

Comment: Above link looks good from cursory inspection?

Comment: The book at the link provided @FelixKling is a great place to read about this topic.

Answer (score 3):

#### OOP in JavaScript without prototypal inheritance

Consider the following `keyValueStore` object :

```
var keyValueStore = (function() {
    var count = 0;
    var kvs = function() {
        count++;
        this.data = {};
        this.get = function(key) { return this.data[key]; };
        this.set = function(key, value) { this.data[key] = value; };
        this.delete = function(key) { delete this.data[key]; };
        this.getLength = function() {
            var l = 0;
            for (p in this.data) l++;
            return l;
        }
    };
    
    return  { // Singleton public properties
        'create' : function() { return new kvs(); },
        'count' : function() { return count; }
    };
})();
```

I can create a new instance of this object by doing this :

```
kvs = keyValueStore.create();
```

Each instance of this object would have the following public properties :

- `data`
- `get`
- `set`
- `delete`
- `getLength`

Now, suppose we create 100 instances of this `keyValueStore` object. Even though `get`, `set`, `delete`, `getLength` will do the exact same thing for each of these 100 instances, every instance has its own copy of this function.

---

#### OOP in JavaScript with prototypal inheritance

Now, imagine if you could have just a single `get`, `set`, `delete` and `getLength` copy, and each instance would reference that same function. This would be better for performance and require less memory.

That's where prototypes come in. A prototype is a "blueprint" of properties that is inherited but not copied by instances. So this means that it exists only once in memory for all instances of an object and is shared by all of those instances.

Now, consider the `keyValueStore` object again. I could rewrite it like this :

```
var keyValueStore = (function() {
    var count = 0;
    var kvs = function() {
        count++;
        this.data = {};
    };

    kvs.prototype = {
        'get' : function(key) { return this.data[key]; },
        'set' : function(key, value) { this.data[key] = value; },
        'delete' : function(key) { delete this.data[key]; },
        'getLength' : function() {
            var l = 0;
            for (p in this.data) l++;
            return l;
        }
    };

    return  {
        'create' : function() { return new kvs(); },
        'count' : function() { return count; }
    };
})();
```

This does EXACTLY the same as the previous version of the `keyValueStore` object, except that all of its methods are now put in a prototype. What this means, is that all of the 100 instances now share these four methods instead of each having their own copy.

---

#### Resources

For a basic introduction into the matter, see eg. [**inheritance and the prototype chain**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Inheritance_and_the_prototype_chain) at the [**MDN website**](https://developer.mozilla.org/nl/).

For a more in depth look into prototypal inheritance, see eg. [**Aadit M Shah**](https://stackoverflow.com/users/783743/aadit-m-shah)'s article [**Why Prototypal Inheritance Matters**](http://aaditmshah.github.io/why-prototypal-inheritance-matters/) and [**Kyle Simpson**](https://stackoverflow.com/users/228852/kyle-simpson)'s online book [**You Don't Know JS: this & Object Prototypes**](https://github.com/getify/You-Dont-Know-JS/blob/master/this%20%26%20object%20prototypes/README.md).

Comment: You just wrote a perfectly good argument for optimizing runtimes, not for exposing prototypes to end users.

Comment: And since we know premature optimization is the root of all evil you also wrote a very good argument against ever using `prototype`.

Comment: Seemed like a perfectly good example to me of *one* thing prototype does....inheritance. Nor do I think its premature optimization. When you **know** better.... **do** better.

Comment: @djechlin : AFAIK, the use of prototypal inheritance is typically encouraged for custom objects (because it's better for memory & performance) and discouraged for standard objects (because you're not supposed to mess with standard objects). Amiwrong here?

Comment: I've personally used prototypical inheritance for pseudoclasses because I work mostly in a Java-inspired code base.